# How to output pd.crosstab function in python using survey weight?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a weighted crosstab in pandas/python as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.crosstab(df.income1, df.benefits1, 
            values=df.survey_weight, aggfunc=sum)
```

However, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
pd.crosstab(df.income1, df.benefits1, 
            values=df.survey_weight, aggfunc=sum)
  File "<ipython-input-57-6e8cfb6762b2>", line 1
    pd.crosstab(df.income1, df.benefits1,
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Any suggestions, please? I can output the crosstab when I run the two first expressions within the bracket.

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6471 entries, 0 to 11549
Data columns (total 3 columns):
survey_weight     6471 non-null float64
income1       3703 non-null float64
benefits1       588 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), float64(2)
memory usage: 467.8 KB
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Now updated, thanks :)

Comment: it seems to be a whitespace issue, can you run it without the line break? Also, please include a data sample or at least `df.info()`

Comment: It doesn't run without the line break

Comment: Now updated with df.info()

Comment: I've tried adding .astype(int) to each part of the expression

Comment: try using bracket notion i.e `pd.crosstab(df['income1'], df['benefits1'], 
            values=df['survey_weight'], aggfunc=sum)`

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't make any difference... thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the whitespace issue is caused by copying and pasting the code... I typed it out and it worked. Thanks to those that posted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an example as this comes up in google searches, for a single weighted crosstab the following works:

```py
dt = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], "b": [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]}
).assign(weight=1)
```

data:

```
|   a |   b |   weight |
|----:|----:|---------:|
|   1 |   1 |        1 |
|   1 |   2 |        1 |
|   1 |   2 |        1 |
|   1 |   2 |        1 |
|   2 |   1 |        1 |
|   2 |   1 |        1 |
|   2 |   2 |        1 |
|   2 |   2 |        1 |
```

Compute crosstab:

```py
pd.crosstab(dt["a"], dt["b"], dt["weight"], aggfunc=sum)
```

outputs:

```
|   a |   1 |   2 |
|----:|----:|----:|
|   1 |   1 |   3 |
|   2 |   2 |   2 |
```

For percentages use normalize - see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html